# How to tell which tab is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and I currently have 3 tabs on a page like so

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#one" aria-controls="one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">One </a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#two" aria-controls="two" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Two </a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#three" aria-controls="three" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Three</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Currently I can call this to get me to activate/show a specific tab like

```
 $('.nav-tabs a[href="#one"]').tab('show');
```

But let say I am on another tab and I update something on that tab, and then I want to show that active tab. How would I do this?

UPDATE
I added this

```
var activetab = $('.allschedules').find('li.active');
```

which returns me an object with properties of the current tab. How do I get teh name of the a href?

Comment: it depends on what is your triggering point to display the tab. Technically, the tab needs to be selected for you to perform any update.

Comment: yea basically I want to do an update and refresh the page to reflect the changes and load the current tab. Hope that made sense.

Comment: Just do this : $('.allschedules').find('li.active a').attr("href");

Comment: how are you doing the update? can index containers easily and match to tabs index

Comment: @DinoMyte that is exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: @JacobRuvalcaba , what you're asking is fairly fundamental stuff here..  I would suggest you become familiar with the properties of the elements you're doing a selection on by looking at the jQuery documentation. Also, you should become familiar with the developer tools available on your browser, in particular.. you should set break points and review the objects in your developer tools console.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a 2nd query to find the child `<a>` element, and then check its `hash` property to get the name from the `href`.

```js
var activeTabName = $('li.active').find('a')[0].hash;
$('#active-tab-name').text(activeTabName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#one" aria-controls="one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">One </a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#two" aria-controls="two" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Two </a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#three" aria-controls="three" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Three</a></li>
</ul>

<span id="active-tab-name"></span>
```